# How to work with selection range in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have VBA to add a strikethrough to selected text but could not find any method to do that.

This is recorded action that I want.

```
ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=7, Length:=5).Font
```

Here I want to strike through selection. Does Excel have a selection object as we have in Word?

Comment: If you have selected some text in cell, you will be edit mode. How would you run vba then? If you figure out a way to run your code while in edit mode than having part of text in a cell selected, `ActiveCell.Characters.Font.Strikethrough = True` will work for that selected text.

Comment: As I was not able to run macro while in edit mode, I asked the question. Got the answer that it is not possible to run macro in edit mode

Comment: After trying from some time, what I was able to do is this: Kept code editor open, switched to excel, selected some text in a cell, switched to code editor from task bar, hit 'F8' ('F5' may also work), switched again to excel to find that selected text is stroked exactly how you want but still in edit mode. Of-course this does not help in practical situation, still documented for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run on a selection of cells, something like:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng1 As Range
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    Set rng1 = Selection
    For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
        If Len(rng2.Value2) > 12 Then rng2.Characters(7, 5).Font.Strikethrough = True
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not the case what I want. I already have the code, Just want to run macro on specific text within cell that is selected. not the selected cell. This is not possible as far as I know. Pankaj's comment gives the affirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can work directly with the cells, no need to activate. I'm on mobile, but something like

```
cells(2,1).Select
 Selection.font.strikethrough=true
```

can be re-coded as `cells(2,1).font.strikethrough = true`

Or to follow your example, `ActiveCell.font.strikethrough= true`

Or

`ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=7, Length:=5).Font.Strikethrough= true` may work, I've never used it with `characters ()` so I'm not positive

Comment: As I have told, this is not the case what I want. I already have the code, Just want to run macro on specific text within cell that is selected. not the selected cell

Comment: @Rahul - This should work, just adjust the `Start` and `Length`, and this will run on any cell.  If you know the text you  want to strikethrough, just get the start and end character "index" and adjust.  If that doesn't work, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know the start and end absolutely. They are selected. I means start and end is not fixed. I figure out that excel have customization option for strikethrough. Solved my problem.

Comment: @Rahul - I'm confused - you have a cell, and you want to strikethrough only a part of that cell, but you don't know how to determine which character to start and end at, via a formula?  What part of the cells' text do you want strikenthrough?

Comment: The selected text. I want to strikethrough the text while it is selected. It is not possible with vba as vba can't be run while in edit mode. See the comment of pabkaj in my question.

Comment: @Rahul - you're trying to do this in Excel, correct? Or run this in Word? I don't get how `ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=7, Length:=5).Font.Strikethrough= true` doesn't work for you. (You can replace `ActiveCell` with `Selection` to use a `.Select`ed cell).

Comment: it is working but that is not what I wanted. I wanted to strike through only when I am in edit mode with some random selection. [ not (Start:=7, Length:=5)]. It is not possible. Got it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99216/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-rahul).